# How do I move ExpressionEngine (EE) to another server?

Tags: expressionengine

What are the best steps to take to prevent bugs and/or data loss in moving servers?

EDIT: Solved, but I should specify I mean in the typical shared hosting environment e.g. DreamHost or GoDaddy.

Comment: This needs more detail to be answerable

Comment: This is a good question. I think your edit is also quite sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EE User Guide offers a reasonably extensive guide to [Moving ExpressionEngine to Another Server](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/operations/moving.html) and if you follow all of these steps then you will have everything you need to try again if any bugs or data loss occur.

1. Verify Server Compatibility
2. Synchronize Templates
3. Back-up Database and Files
4. Prepare the New Database
5. Copy Files and Folders
6. Verify File Permissions
7. Update database.php
8. Verify index.php and admin.php
9. Log In and Update Paths
10. Clear Caches

As suggested by Bitmanic, a dynamic config.php file helps with moving environments tremendously. Check out Leevi Graham's [Config Bootstrap](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-config-bootstrap) for a quick and simple solution. This is helpful for dev/staging/prod environments too!

Comment: When you're setting up a fresh install, or migrating an existing site, give this [permissions setting utility](http://quickshiftin.com/blog/2013/10/expression-engine-permissions-utility/) a try!

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap config is the smartest method (Newism has a free bootstrap config module). I think it works best on fresh installs myself, but ymmv.

If you've been given an existing EE system and need to move it, there are a few simple tools that can help:

- [REElocate](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reelocate): all the EE 2.x path and config options, in one place. Swap one URL for another in setup, check what's being set and push the button.
- [Greenery](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/greeny): Again, one module to rule them all. I've not used this but it's got a good rating.

So install, set permissions, move files and and DB, and then use either free module. If you find that not all the images or CSS instantly comes back online, check your template base paths (in template prefs) and permissions.

I'm also presuming you have access to the old DB. If not, and you can't add something simple like PHPMyAdmin to back it up, try:

- [Backup Pro(ish)](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/backup-proish): A free backup module for files and db. Easy enough that you should introduce it to the site users (most never consider backups). All done through the EE CP. The zipped output can easily be moved to the new server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the answer is the same as any other system -- export your entire database, and download all of your files (both system and anything uploaded by users - images, etc). Then, mirror this process by importing/uploading to the new server.

Before I run my export, I like to use the [Deeploy Helper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/deeploy-helper) module to change all of my file paths in EE to the new server's settings.

Answer (score 0):

Preventing data loss primarily revolves around the database and upload directories.

Does your website allow users to interact with the database? If so at some point you'll need to turn off EE to prevent DB changes. If not that you don't have too much to worry about as you can track and changes on the database end between the old and new servers.

Answer (score 0):

Both Philip and Derek offer good advice for migrating EE. I've also found that having a bootstrap config file helps tremendously - especially since you can configure your file upload directories directly via config values now (as of EE2.4, I think).

For related information, please check out the answers to [this similar Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094609/more-efficient-expressionengine-server-moves).